# Can projectiles pass through enemies?

Tags: borderlands

If yes, what weapons allow this? How does the damage work? Will the impact on the first enemy hit by the projectile, lessen damage to the second enemy hit?

This is so I'll know if it's worth it to position myself so I could hit enemies in situations like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Actually bullets (and rockets) do occasionally pass through enemies doing zero damage. It's most obvious with the high-damage, low ROF weapons, when it happens, helix launchers in particular.  It seems to be a bug that was never patched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, bullets do not pass through enemies. To my knowledge, no special weapon effect (red text) does it either.

That's Borderlands, though. Can't say anything about Borderlands 2.

As a side note, some special weapon effects cause bullets to ricochet, but trying to aim with that effect in mind is probably more trouble than it's worth. There's also splash damage from explosions, and elemental effects might spread to nearby enemies even if they have not been hit by a bullet.

Comment: In Borderlands 2, Zer0's B0re skill allows bullets to pierce through enemies. But I believe that you're correct - nothing in the first Borderlands allows bullets to pass through enemies.